# How to get the current value from the foreach loop using jquery and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, foreach

Here is my code:

```js
<section class="panel">
    <header class="panel-heading">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_edit" onclick="modal_edit('<?php echo base_url() ?>leave/save')"   class="btn btn-default pull-right" href=""><i class="fa fa-calendar-minus-o"></i>&nbsp;Add Leave</a>
      <!--  <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>leave/apply_leave"><i class="fa fa-calendar-minus-o"></i>&nbsp;Appsssly Leave</a>   -->
        <h2 class="panel-title">Employee Leave History</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none" id="datatable-tabletools" data-swf-path="assets/vendor/jquery-datatables/extras/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Leave Type </th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th class="hidden-phone">From date - To date</th>
                    <th class="hidden-phone">Reason</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php $count = 1 ?>
                <?php foreach ($leave as $leave): ?>
                    <tr class="gradeX">
                        <td><?php echo $count++ ?></td>
                        <td id="name"><?php echo $leave->first_name . ' ' . $leave->last_name ?>
                            <input type="button" id="employee_id" value="<?php echo $leave->employee_id ?>"/> 
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $leave->name ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $leave->subject ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $leave->from_date . ' - ' . $leave->to_date ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $leave->reason ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <select  id="status" data-plugin-selectTwo class="form-control populate placeholder" >
                                <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                <option value="Granted">Granted</option>
                                <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
                            </select>
  
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
              <!--  //onchange="update_status('<?php echo base_url().'status/leave/'.$employee_id ?>')"  onchange="myFunction();" -->
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>

</section>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#status").ready(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            //var y =$('#status').val();
            //alert($('#status option:selected').val() );
           //alert($("#status").select());
       // var x = $('#employee_id').val();
       // alert(this.x)    
        console.log(1);
            $.ajax({
               url   :'<?php echo base_url() ?>leave/status',
               data  : {
                         status : $(this).val(),
                        employee_id : $('#employee_id').val(),
                        // name : $('#name').val(),
                      },
               dataType: 'json',
               success : function(response) {
                   alert(response);
                   
               }
              
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```

I have foreach loop and there is a drop-down list with values. If i have 4 loops then I want to update leaves for only 1-st loop, means `id = 1`, using `ajax` it works perfectly.

Now I want to update the leave for id = 2 but the problem is, `jquery` is not getting the `id = 2` value, it selects the first id value means `id =1` .
now I would like to update the `id = 2` to update their leave as well.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: dude please i struggle almost a day.

Comment: **WHAT IS YOUR QUESTION?** "I struggle each day" is not a question. Where are you stuck, what have you tried.

Comment: dude please i struggle almost a day.  i have leave applied table, where i want to update the leave status for employee with out page loading. so i used the ajax to update the leave status. in foreach i displayed the leave details i used drop down having pending,granted. i want to update the employee leave status. in my code it selects only the 1st elements(means 1st loop of the employee ) & it update successfully. but the 2nd elements is not updating. my jquery is not select the 2ndloop.i want to accept the all the current loop values so that i can update the leave status without page loading.

Comment: i tried this keyword and val(), ('selected').val(); i have commented in my java script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use same id multiple times.
First change in your html

```
<?php foreach ($leave as $leave): ?>
<tr class="gradeX">
    <td><?php echo $count++ ?></td>
    <td id="name"><?php echo $leave->first_name . ' ' . $leave->last_name ?>
        <input type="button" class="employee_id" value="<?php echo $leave->employee_id ?>"/> 
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $leave->name ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $leave->subject ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $leave->from_date . ' - ' . $leave->to_date ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $leave->reason ?></td>
    <td>
        <select  id="<?php echo $leave->employee_id ?>" class="status" data-plugin-selectTwo class="form-control populate placeholder" >
            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="Granted">Granted</option>
            <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
        </select>

    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In Javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".status").change(function () {
            var employee_id = $(this).prop('id');  
            var status = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
               url   :'<?php echo base_url() ?>leave/status',
               data  : {'status' : status, 'employee_id' : employee_id},
               dataType: 'json',
               success : function(response) {
                   alert(response);

               }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: that work nice, but still lot more to do. i want to dynamically display the value in the dropdown foreach loop. using jquery any idea please.

Comment: @Rakesh is there any bug remaining ..?

Comment: dispaly the value dynamically in dropdown list using jquery.  you can my post where i taken <select > tag i want to display the value dyanmically for each time. any idea

Comment: @Rakesh you mean selected value in `<select>` tag.

Comment: yes select tag in <options> i want to display the selected value from db in the 1st <options> tag using jquery.

Comment: @Rakesh, you can use `<option value="Pending" <?php echo ($leave->status =='Pending')? 'selected':' '; ?> >Pending</option>`

Comment: thanks for you'r interest, i really appreciate. I already used the same, the problem was it display the value twice.for eg. Granted,Granted,Pending. that way i try to use jquery to display. i previously tried the jquery to display the single value but i not used in for loop. i tried to use the different method but no use. you have any idea please help